# printing contents in xml using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I am trying to convert xml to xslt using the script below. The conversion is done flawlessly. Now, i want to write the contents into a new xml file. When i try to do so, I get just one line in my xml file. However when I print it in console i get multiline outputs. Can any one spot what I am doing wrong?

```
import lxml.etree as ET


dom = ET.parse("1.xml")
xslt = ET.parse("1.xsl")
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(newdom)
newdom.write("output.xml")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved my problem

```
with open('output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(newdom)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're already writing everything to the "output.xml" file. Feel free to post a snippet of your output file, as well as for the input ones.

If the only problem is that you want it be structured across multiple lines, compared to be a one-liner, you could just set the pretty print flag to true.

`newdom.write("output.xml", pretty_print=True)`

Output example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I even tried what you suggested but when I print newdom it has the complete file. But when I write to xml file it just has the first line.